# How to colour individual rows in Cell-Based NSTableVew in Swift 5

Tags: xcode, swift5, nstableview, nstextfieldcell

I am trying to show items in `NSTableView` but one of them (the item that previously was activated by an action (its name is stored in `alreadyActivatedItem` variable)) should be disabled and shown with a red text.

So far I managed to make disabling work properly.

I just cannot manage colouring the already activated item be red text. My code below will colour ALL cells' text in red.

```
extension PreferencesViewController: NSTableViewDelegate {
    
    // disable selecting the already activated item
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, shouldSelectRow row: Int) -> Bool {
                        
        return !(myArray[row].name == alreadyActivatedItem)
    }
    
    // colouring the already activated item in red (it is also disabled)
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, willDisplayCell cell: Any, for tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) {
        
        guard let c = cell as? NSTextFieldCell else {
            return
        }

        if c.stringValue == alreadyActivatedItem {
            c.textColor = .red
        }

    }
}
```

I also tried an other way:

```
// colouring the already activated item in red (it is also disabled)
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, willDisplayCell cell: Any, for tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) {

    guard let c = tableColumn?.dataCell(forRow: row) as? NSTextFieldCell else {
        return
    }
    
    if c.stringValue == alreadyActivatedRow {
        c.textColor = .red
    }
}
```

In both cases I will have all the rows with red text:

[see as all items are red text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlKcI.png)

While debugging, I can see that:

- `let c = cell as? NSTextFieldCell` seems to get the current row's cell, at least I get back the row's `stringValue` correctly with `c.stringValue`
- `if c.stringValue == alreadyActivatedRow` seems to work good, at least it only steps inside if the condition is true.

So why still do all the items get red colour?

How to achieve my goal then?

(Xcode 11.3.1, Swift 5.1.3)

Comment: See [tableView(_:willDisplayCell:for:row:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableviewdelegate/1533829-tableview) "Because aCell is reused for every row in aTableColumn, the delegate must set the display attributes both when drawing special cells and when drawing standard cells.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cells are reused. You have to add an `else` clause to set the color always to a defined state.

```
if c.stringValue == alreadyActivatedItem {
    c.textColor = .red
} else {
    c.textColor = .black
}
```

Or simpler

```
 c.textColor = c.stringValue == alreadyActivatedItem ? .red : .black
```

I recommend even a view based table view and Cocoa Bindings.

Comment: Works pretty good! Thanks a lot, @vadian! If only I know where in the hell in Apple's documentation could I red it??? E.g. why cannot read it at NSTextFieldCell that 'hey stupid programmer, be aware of that cells are reused, so... '?! I have waisted 7 hours this morning to make it work! Thank you Apple!

Comment: This behavior is actually related to the table view data source rather than directly to the cell. But it's described in the documentation that cells are reused.